# Who is the narrator of the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide book?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, books

Some of the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* appears to be written from an in-universe character in first person. Evidence of this can be found throughout, but as an example, from the section on Evereska, p. 82:

> I would be remiss if I didn't mention Evereska, but I will be brief for I have no desire to publish all its secrets. I shall endeavor to describe my own homeland in as unbiased a way as I might, but I must warn: I am a daughter of the Greycloak Hills, and its mists yet roil through my soul as surely as elven blood does through my veins.

So from the above we can assume the narrator is a female elf or half-elf. However, I have been unable to find any mention by name, such as an intro like the one at the beginning of *Volo's Guide to Monsters*.

Who is the narrator of the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Chapter 2 of the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* is narrated by five Faerûnians.

The introduction to [Chapter 2: The Sword Coast and the North](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north) says (SCAG, p. 43; emphasis mine):

> This chapter details many of the locales of the Sword Coast and the
>   North, **as seen through the eyes and recollections of a person living
>   in Faerûn.** Rather than being exhaustive descriptions, what follows are
>   snippets of information **drawn from the experience of five individuals
>   who have traversed, lived in, and explored these areas**. Like any other
>   narrators, they have opinions and biases, and may be drawing
>   conclusions from incomplete information. No one in the Realms knows
>   everything about any subject, even its oldest and most learned sages,
>   and the views formed from such incomplete information can often
>   suggest an inaccurate conclusion. This is not to say that any of the
>   information the narrators provide is false, only that they may not be
>   entirely knowledgeable in their declarations.

The ["Lords' Alliance"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north#TheLordsAlliance) section is narrated by (p. 43):

> [...] Andwe Cururen, a half-elf native of Silverymoon who was once a
>   Knight in Silver (a member of the city’s army), and now serves as an
>   emissary and, when necessary, an active agent for the Lords’ Alliance.

The ["Dwarfholds of the North"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north#DwarfholdsoftheNorth) section is narrated by (p. 59):

> [...] Drorn Waranvil, a longbeard (dwarf elder) who is a retired veteran
>   of the Iron Guard of Citadel Adbar and the Citadel Guards of Felbarr.

The ["Island Kingdoms"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north#IslandKingdoms) section is narrated by (p. 66):

> [...] Gardorra Burr, a gnome sailor who has spent most of her two hundred
>   years traversing the Sea of Swords.

The ["Independent Realms"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north#IndependentRealms) section (including the bit quoted in the question) is narrated by (p. 73):

> [...] Aedyn Graymantle, a moon elf ranger who hails from Evereska.

The ["Underdark"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/the-sword-coast-and-the-north#TheUnderdark) section is narrated by (p. 99):

> [...] Oshgir, a half-orc warrior who was captured by a duergar raiding
>   party, sold to a Zhentarim agent, captured by drow, and then escaped
>   his captivity by killing an overseer and fleeing to Blingdenstone.